# eBay API: findItemsAdvanced returning "internal server error" with errorcode "500"

Tags: vb.net, internal-server-error, ebay-api

I'm trying to send a `findItemsAdvanced` request to the eBay API from VB 2012 .NET - however each time I get an "internal server error" with errorcode "500" upon `request.GetResponse()` where `request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1")`. I do the request via POST and in XML format with the lines

```
Dim Xml_bytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlstr)
request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1")
'... code setting HEADERS, see below
request.Method = "POST"
request.ContentLength = Xml_bytes.Length
request.ContentType = "text/xml"
Dim requestStream As System.IO.Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
requestStream.Write(Xml_bytes, 0, Xml_bytes.Length)
requestStream.Close()
```

The code setting the headers I left out, instead here the actual finished headers I supply:

```
X-EBAY-SOA-SERVICE-NAME: FindingService
X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME: findItemsAdvanced
X-EBAY-SOA-SERVICE-VERSION: 1.0.0
X-EBAY-SOA-GLOBAL-ID: EBAY-DE
X-EBAY-SOA-SECURITY-APPNAME: ****
X-EBAY-SOA-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: XML
Content-Type: text/xml
```

And finally the actual XML code which is supplied (through `xmlstr` var above):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<findItemsAdancedRequest xmlns='http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services'>
<keywords>caddy</keywords>
<categoryId>77994</categoryId>
<Version>779</Version>
<paginationInput><entriesPerPage>10</entriesPerPage>
</paginationInput>
</findItemsAdvancedRequest>
```

My main problem is: it does work perfectly with `findItemsByKeywords`! With the exact same code, only changing the find method and leaving out the `<categoryId>77994</categoryId>`.

What I tried to do:

1. different sites (US, german,..)
2. different categories and keywords.
3. live AND sandbox APIs with the correct appIDs
4. including or excluding `X-EBAY-SOA-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT` and/or
   `X-EBAY-SOA-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT` from the header

It's always the same: it works fine with `findItemsByKeyword` but I get the "internal server error" with `findItemsAdvanced`

I have run out of ideas - any suggestions?
Thanks!